# How to say "speakers" as in electronic speakers?

Tags: translation

On Google translate it shows "speakers" as 
スピーカー. Is this the correct translation for electronic speakers or is it something else?

Comment: Yes. http://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%B9%E3%83%94%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC

Comment: FWIW, I don't necessarily think this is a translation question.

Answer (score 3):

"speaker" is translated as:

- スピーカー (electric device)
- 話者 or スピーカー (as in native *speaker* of English)
- 演者 or スピーカー (as in speaker of a conference)

---

Google Translate is the least credible resource. Please try other sites first (like [this one](http://tangorin.com/general/speaker)) if you want more info for a specific word.

- [List of online English-Japanese dictionaries](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/761#761)